# How to get some properties from list using lambda expression in c#

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have a list of customer as show below

```
 List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>()
            {
                new Customer{Id=1,Name="Abc",Address="USA",Mobile="78978797989" },
                new Customer{Id=2,Name="XYZ",Address="UK",Mobile="985654454545" },
                new Customer{Id=3,Name="Kafus",Address="London",Mobile="06548754555" }
            };
```

I want to create a list with only ID and Name from above list means I want only 2 property in my new list object.

I am trying to do some code like this but I didn't get using lambda expression

```
var lists = customers.Select(s=>s.Id,s=>s.Name).ToList();
```

But I am getting error 
    Can anybody help me with lambda expression to get lists with two property i.e Id and Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sweeper said

You should use the [Anonymous Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) syntax

and this another [way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq#standard-query-operator-extension-methods) to do that:

```
var list = (from customer in customers select new { customer.Id, customer.Name }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Tuple if you love Lambda:

```
var list = customers.Select(x => new Tuple<int, string>(x.Id, x.Name)).ToList();
```

or

```
var list = customers.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Name }).ToList();
```